# Is there any way to increase the display size of an old 3gp video without converting it?

Tags: resolution, 3gp

I have about 100 3gp videos from 2005-2008 which are really poor quality.

I dont want to convert them because it will surely decrease the quality further. I have tried with regular commercial video converters and the finer lines dissapear or become more blurry.

I dont mind the ugly blotchy pixels known with 3gp phones and videos from those years, but is there any way to basically project the original video in its original small resolution so that I can view it on a large monitor and then save it like that with the original 3gp quality?

What ive noticed with these videos is that the smaller the viewing area is the clearer the picture quality is, but then obviously I need to view it through a magnifying glass...

So how do I save it as if im viewing it small when actually im viewing it on a large monitor?

Hope i am being clear about what I am looking for...
Please help.

Comment: I don't quite follow... the video's already small in it's original 3gp format, and any video player can do a zoom or "full screen" view. Why would you enlarge the video, then shrink it and save it, when you can just leave it alone and have it's original full quality saved as-is?

Comment: I hear what your saying but in some instances the player doesnt allow zoom or fullscreen view. But since that is a valid point can you suggest anything in terms of improving the quality of a 3gp video?

Comment: Search for a better quality version of the video, online somewhere, youtube, etc? All you can really do is zoom in, and/or find a player that does that. But `ffmpeg` does tons of converting, some settings might keep near the same quality

Comment: Ok thanks, but these are videos that i recorded with my phone. On something completely unrelated though, do you know what the command line is to convert batch mkv's to mp4? Ive been trying but all i managed to do was get one at a time done. So far i got to.           ffmpeg -i S01E01.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4    But the problem is im not a genius at using cmd so i have no knowledge of how exactly to input the command so that it includes all 13 files in the folder.

Comment: If it's just getting the command line working I'd try a bash loop, or maybe xargs, or just copy & paste? Not super familiar with ffmpeg, but it's supposed to do just about anything